# Does Integration along the imaginary axis in the complex plane give an imaginary result?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Given is the following contour integral :

[image: Contour integral along imaginary axis]

The “arc-length” path vanishes according to Jordan’s Lemma.

Now, is it correct to use the residue theorem, and set the Integral along the imaginary axis equal to the imaginary value given by the residue theorem, and set the integral along the real axis equal to the real value ?

I’ve searched on the internet but couldn’t find a single page where this is stated, maybe it’s trivial but I just wanted to be sure.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are we deemed to guess what the integrand is ?

Comment: I meant in a “general case”

Comment: If $f$ is **real-valued** along the real (imaginary) axis, then the integral along that axis will be purely real (imaginary). Otherwise, probably not.

Comment: If we would be asked to evaluate an integral from 0 to infinity of a function like 1/(1+x^2) (typical example) , and thus gamma 1 corresponds exactly to our integral, gamma 2 vanishes but what are we supposed to do with gamma 3 which goes from i*infinity to 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.

By definition we have
$$\int_{\gamma_3} f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z = \int_0^1 f(iR(1-t)) \cdot (-iR) \,\mathrm{d}t = -iR \int_0^1 f(iR(1-t)) \,\mathrm{d}t,$$
which is imaginary for all $R \gt 0$ if and only if $f(\{z \in \mathbb C: \Re z = 0, \Im z \ge 0\}) \subset \mathbb R$ – which is false for a lot of functions.

Answer (score 1):

You must use

$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\,dz+0+\int_{\gamma_3}f(z)\,dz=\sum\text{Residues}$$

whatever the integrand is.

Comment: I would replace $0$ with $o(1)$